# How to add custom lines to MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: sbt, manifest.mf

Adding custom key-value-pairs to the MANIFEST.MF using Build.scala seems not to work. Here is my code:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import java.util.Date

object Build extends Build {

  packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=
    Package.ManifestAttributes( "Build" -> "true" )

}
```

When I add:

```
packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=
  Package.ManifestAttributes( "Sign" -> "true" )
```

To my build.sbt then only `Sign` reaches my MANIFEST.MF. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may want something like this (note the `manifestSettings` added to the settings of the project).

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import java.util.Date
import sbt.Package.ManifestAttributes

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val manifestSettings = Seq(
    packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) += 
         Package.ManifestAttributes( "Build" -> "true" )
  )

  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).settings(manifestSettings: _*)

}
```

Then you should be able to call `package` and have the a jar with the extra manifest entry.

### Edit

To get the `("Buid" -> <current time>)` the `manifestSettings` should be

```
lazy val manifestSettings = Seq(
  packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) += 
           Package.ManifestAttributes( "Build" -> new Date().toString() )
)
```