# How to set Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF to custom classpath?

Tags: sbt

I have to deploy a JAR with a very specific classpath in its MANIFEST.MF.  How would I configure sbt so the packaged JAR has this specific classpath (for example):

```
.
lib/abc.jar
lib/xyz.jar
../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.2.3/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.3/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
../../lib/maven/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
../../lib/maven/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
../../lib/maven/joda-time/joda-time/2.5/joda-time-2.5.jar
../../lib/maven/log4j/log4j/1.2.11/log4j-1.2.11.jar
../../lib/database/SQLServer2008/3.0.1301.101/sqljdbc4.jar
```

(The real one will include Scala too, of course.)

Comment: Could this be of help maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546523/adding-custom-lines-to-manifest-mf-using-sbt

Comment: Where do the jars/paths come from? Are they dependencies of a project? What task do you execute to build the jar?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: The JARs are dependencies for running the application.  When I use SBT to compile/test, SBT gets them via Ivy.  But in the environment where the executable is deployed, there is a Maven structure (the ../../lib/maven/) that is common to many executables.  Basically I have to make sure any JARs I use are in that ../../lib/maven structure before I deploy.

Comment: @gknauth Alternatively to depending on jars with relative paths you might want to consider bundling them with your application using, for instance, https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: @DaleWijnand: Thanks, I do bundle with sbt-assembly when that is permitted/appropriate, but in this particular instance I have to use the relative paths.  I appreciate the suggestion though--sbt-assembly is something I had to figure out not long ago for a different use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding something like this to your build:

```
val classPath = Seq(
  ".",
  "lib/abc.jar",
  "lib/xyz.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.2.3/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.3/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/joda-time/joda-time/2.5/joda-time-2.5.jar",
  "../../lib/maven/log4j/log4j/1.2.11/log4j-1.2.11.jar",
  "../../lib/database/SQLServer2008/3.0.1301.101/sqljdbc4.jar"
)

packageOptions += Package.ManifestAttributes(
  "Class-Path" -> classPath.mkString(" ")
)
```

Comment: I'll try that when I'm next at the computer with this project.  Thanks.

Comment: Dale Wijnand:  Your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Should be something automatic using the dependencies defined in the module, including transient dependencies.