# Is it possible to run an application in CloudFoundry without Garden?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Can I deploy (push) and application into CloudFoundry and run it outside of a Garden/Warden container, just as a process?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you want to run it outside a container?

Comment: Trying to fix this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899894/how-to-deploy-a-scala-application-with-filenames-larger-than-242-characters-in-c